# WordPress is Not Setting PHP $_POST on Custom Ajax

Tags: ajax

I am trying to Post and set some value on a PHP file called `session.php` using jQuery Ajax Post like

```
$("#up-data").on("click", function(){
        var data= { 
            url : 'www.google.com', 
            product : 'Map' 
        };
        var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_set.ajaxurl,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
        }
});
         request.done(function( data) {
         console.log(data);
        });

        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
          console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        }); 
    });
```

looks like the POST is working fine here because I am not getting any error plus I am getting the `Map www.google.com` in the Response of fire bug and also in console for `.done()` without any error message

[image]

but in the session PHP

```
$u = $_POST["url"];
$p = $_POST["product"];
echo $u . "  " .$p ;
```

is returning nothing without any error message

[image]

Can you please let me know what I am missing or doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having some doubts about your code. IF your using WordPress you should use https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

So you no session.php, but a function:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_foobar', 'my_ajax_foobar_handler' );

function my_ajax_foobar_handler() {
    $u = $_POST["url"];
    $p = $_POST["product"];
    echo $u . "  " .$p ;
    wp_die();
}
```

and simplify yours JS

```
jQuery.post(
    my_foobar_client.ajaxurl, 
    {
        'action': 'foobar',
        'url' : 'www.google.com', 
        'product' : 'Map' 
    }, 
    function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```